# Show org-todo-list with specific category

Tags: org-agenda, org-mode

Can I pass an argument to `(org-todo-list)` so the buffer will only show item a specific category?

I tried something like `(org-todo-list "personal")`, but had no success.

I can still use `<` over a category, once I am in the `org-agenda-mode`. Is there a way to combine these steps into "open a new org todo view filtered by category"?

Comment: after using the filter in die `agend-mode` the powerline says something like `<+personal>`, maybe that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `org-todo-list` directly, so use a tags search instead.  Despite the name `org-tags-view` will match arbitrary properties, not just tags.  Setting the first argument of `org-tags-view` to `t` will restrict to only todo items.  For example `(org-tags-view t "CATEGORY=\"personal\"")` will show all todo items with `CATEGORY` "personal".

You also access this using the `M` option of `org-agenda` or by creating a custom agenda view of type `tags-todo`.